# Separating odd and even pulses in a pulse train

Tags: digital-logic, design, pulse, wave, circuits

How would one go about separating odd and even pulses in a pulse train and displaying them using LED indicators?

A schematic would be of great help.

Comment: Welcome to EE Stack Exchange! For asking questions on this site, I recommend framing the exact problem as clearly as possible and in complete sentences. Also, bold text and pleas won't make answers come any faster.

Comment: Yeah definitely! Was in a big confusion and got no answers anywhere so the bold text sorry about that! :)

Comment: Homework question with zero effort

Comment: yes! but no since its not exactly a home work 
It is a game and was questioned by my intelligent friend and also I was not aware of the topic

Comment: I thought it was a info sharing page so asked you guys! and also where would you go if you don't know something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A counter circuit would do the trick. Increment count on rising edge of pulse, output is the LSB of the counter. A t-flip flop would be useful. I'll leave the exactly implementation to you as this seems like a homework type of question.

Comment: Thank you very much!
But still how will I be able to separate the odd and even pulses from that counters?
How am I be able to figure that out?
Also the LSB gives only the even values right

Comment: Why did you accept the answer if you don't understand it?

Comment: understood and got the answer!